whitelabel error page on graphql voyager endpoint
I tried integrating voyager in a graphQL Kotlin running application to visualize the schema.
I have added below dependency for the same -
             <dependency>
                <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
                <artifactId>voyager-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>11.1.0</version>
            </dependency>

Whitelabel error page is coming up on trying to access http://localhost:8080/voyager after adding above dependency. Is there any other step that needs to be done to integrate voyager?
(There is no issue with graphql playground endpoint, thats working perfectly)
Also if there are any other simple alternatives to visualize graphql schema in a graphql Kotlin application, please do suggest
